# Running interrelated methods continuously using java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have written application which downloads data from a website  every 10 mins and writes to a file.Then these files are merged into one file and then R program is run on this merged file to perform sentiment analysis and result is stored in hbase.

I want the process of merging files,running R and then storing to HBase to run continuously on the downloaded data.

For running R,we are running R script from java program.We have used Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method to run R program but it doesn't wait for R program to complete and method in the next line starts executing.Using p.waitFor() did not help .

Below is the snippet of the code.

public class runRprogram {

```
public static String rOutputFile; 
public static HashMap catMap;
public static HashMap dtMap;
public static HashMap sentMap;

public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    //runR("D:\\workspace\\Out100316.txt","D:\\workspace\\Clean_Out100316");

    cleanupTempFiles();
    mergeFiles();
    rRun();
    Thread.sleep(60000); 
    //sleep for 10 secs and give time for R program to finish

    rOutputFile = "D:\\TweetsData\\TweetsProcessed\\Out1004224944.txt";
    incrementHBaseCounts();

}
```

public static void rRun() throws IOException {

```
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        String execom = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.1\\bin\\i386\\Rscript.exe";
        String rpath = "D:\\workspace\\R_scripts\\TextMining.Funtion.R";
        String inputFile = "D:\\TData\\TTemp\\ConcatenatedFile.txt";
        rOutputFile = "D:\\TData\\TProcessed\\Out" + formatter.format("%1$tm%1$td%1$tH%1$tM%1$tS", new Date()) + ".txt";
        String[] command = {"cmd","/c",execom,rpath,inputFile,rOutputFile };
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
        //int status=p.waitFor();


        System.out.println("R - Program executed");

}
```

}

What approach should I use to do merge then run R and finally store results in Hbase?Should I use timer class??

Comment: When you say continuously, do you mean sequentially (one after the other)? What do you mean by *`p.waitFor()` did not help*?

Comment: Post the code where you are starting R script

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: Probably the `exec()` call fails, have you read its output (i.e., `while (br.ready()) System.out.println( br.readLine() );` )? It might help you a bit.

Comment: @assylias :
The complete process is continuous. 
step1 : The data is being downloaded every 10 mins in multiple files. 
step2 : The downloaded data is then merged into one file. 
step3 : Once merging to one file is complete R script is run to perform a sentiment analysis. 
step4 : And when it completes data is stored in hbase. 

All these steps are to be repeated continuously in the same order. 

waitFor is method in Process class. Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); int status=p.waitFor();

Comment: @snehalata what do you mean when you say that waitFor does not help? It does not block until your script completes? It is difficult to answer specifically without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Sounds like the script you run from the exec() call doesn't wait for the R code to execute.  You might check there.

Comment: @Zagrev :Yes.The exec method returns immediately and does not wait for R code to execute.How should I modify code to wait for R code to complete execution?

Comment: I was trying to determine how many layers are part of the exec() call. There is the Java layer, the R script engine, and the R program you are running. Make sure you pass the appropriate command line arguments to ensure the shell script, or bash script, or whatever the exec() call kicks off actually waits for your R program to finish (I don't know R, but something like "wait=true"